# finding probability using Methods of Enumeration

Tags: probability

A computer retail store has 12 personal computers in stock. A customer wants to
purchase three of the computers. Assume that of the 12 computers, 4 are
defective. If the computers are selected at random what is the probability that
exactly one of the purchased computers is defective?

Answer (score 1):

So in total you have ${12 \choose 3}$ choices to choose 3 computers. Now to get one defective computer exactly, you choose 2 good computers in ${8 \choose 2}$ ways, and 1 defective computer in ${4 \choose 1}$ ways. So together you can choose 2 good computers and exactly one defective one in ${8 \choose 2}{4 \choose 1}$.

Now the probability is :  $$\frac{{8 \choose 2}{4 \choose 1}}{{12 \choose 3}}.$$

Try generalizing to variable choices.

Answer (score 0):

This is no more than a generalization: What you need in called hypergeometric probability. There are $n$ total unique items (computers), of then $m<n$ are sampled without replacement (i.e. they are not returned to the set). There are $x<m<n$ special items in this sample. We use some special mesh size $r$ to select $r$ items out of $m$. We want to know the probability to have $x$ special items in this mesh.

Clearly there are $\binom{n}{m}$ ways to select $m$ items out of $n$. Since we want $x$ special items in the mesh (And the rest does not matter), there are $\binom{r}{x} \binom{n-r}{m-x}$ ways of doing so. Hence, the probability to catch $x$ special items is 
$$
P(X=x)=\frac{\binom{r}{x} \binom{n-r}{m-x}}{\binom{n}{m}}
$$